# Modìfy data when eloquent class in laravel return or create/update to database

Tags: php, timezone, laravel-5.1

**E.g:** 
My system have a timezone setting for everyuser ,User 1 is in `UTC+6`, User 2 is in `UTC` , User 3 is in `UTC+3`, my server is `UTC`.

When User update / create a record or Get data from record to datatables, Server will automatically convert the timezone and return to User. Or when user post the data to server, server will automatically convert it to `UTC` depend on the timezone setting of user before saving to database. Anyway to do this ?

I want to do this massive for all class in my project :) Just trying to extend the eloquent class but don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should store data in the database in one timezone (your preferred timezone for example). When you display the data to the user, you can display it based on their timezone easily.

Check out the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. It will allow you to create a Date object, set the time, then change the timezone (to the users timezone), then output in a given format.

Comment: Yes ,my data in the database have store in UTC format ,i mean : 
I have a content__posts table with these collumn id,user_id ,published_date
With this ex data  : 1 ,1 , 1/1/1990 0:00:00
When user (UTC + 12)  retrive it ,we will convert it to usertimezone : 1/1/1990 12:00:00 then show to the datatable .Or when user create a new post with the published_date "1/1/1990 13:00:00" (UTC+12)  ,we will convert it  to UTC : 1/1/1990 1:00:00
Problem is i have many class / table so i cant do this 1 by 1 class , i want to extend the base eloquent class :( 
thankyou

Comment: I guess I don't understand the issue. Why do you need to do this at the entity level? Displaying in a specific format could be done at the controller or view level.

Comment: Because im trying to create a CMS ,if the other one want to extend ,or create a new module and have a same issue  ,they no need to copy and paste my old code to fix this problem ,the system will automatically do this for them